# appengine equivalent of a "NOT IN" query

Tags: google-app-engine

I am coming to Appengine from a relational database background, and was considering how best to accomplish this task.

Basically I have a table of objects and would like to retrieve a pair that a user has never seen.

In mysql for example the most straightforward could be something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM object_pairs
WHERE id NOT IN(
    SELECT object_pair_id
    FROM user_object_pairs
    WHERE user_id = :user_id
)
```

Ideally I'd also like to be able to retrieve a random (or semi-random) pair from the possible results.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this. The SQL query you suggest will be executed by most SQL databases as first constructing an in-memory list of IDs, then doing a linear scan over the table, returning only rows that aren't in the list of IDs. You can do the same in App Engine: get the user's 'seen list', do a query for all entities, and skip those that he's seen before.